# Implementing own bluetooth profile for android

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

I'm trying to implement Handsfree bluetooth profile for android (HF side). I have succesfully connected through rfcomm and it allows me to send/receive AT commands to/from AG. But what about voice? In documentation I have read about synchronous connection, and tried to accept connection from SCO socket:

```
int sock = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_SEQPACKET, BTPROTO_SCO)
```

But nothing happens.

Is this a correct type of socket, or I need something different then SCO?

Comment: Are you succeeded in implementing the profile..?

Comment: No, I did'nt solve problem with creating SCOlink.

Answer (score 0):

You may take inspiration from the class `ScoSocket.java` located in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth`. You will see that it calls native functions rather than `socket(AF_BLUETOOTH...)`. As it used by the Phone app, you may rely on it.

```
/** Connect this SCO socket to the given BT address.
 *  Does not block.
 */
public synchronized boolean connect(String address, String name) {
    if (DBG) log("connect() " + this);
    if (mState != STATE_READY) {
        if (DBG) log("connect(): Bad state");
        return false;
    }
    acquireWakeLock();
    if (connectNative(address, name)) {
        mState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    } else {
        mState = STATE_CLOSED;
        releaseWakeLockNow();
        return false;
    }
}
private native boolean connectNative(String address, String name);
```